# How to load an aspx page from silverlight frame?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, iframe, treeview, navigation

I have two frames in a Silverlight application.

One frame contains a TreeView control. When a user clicks on one of the TreeView's items then I want an ASPX page to be loaded into the next frame.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By aspx I presume you mean an HTML page produced by an aspx page call. You can use the web [browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28VS.95%29.aspx) that was introduced in SL4 though I think it works only in OOB mode.

Comment: The first thing to say about the WebBrowser control is that it only functions in Silverlight Out-Of-Browser applications ( SLOOBs )

Comment: and that's precisely what I did, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to open any URL in a different browser frame as a reaction to a user click on a Silverlight TreeViewItem:

**XAML**

```
<sdk:TreeView Name="_tree" SelectedItemChanged="Tree_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

**C#**

```
private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, 
                                      RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var selection = e.NewValue;

    // Extract URL from selected tree node, perhaps
    var url = ...

    var uri = new Uri(url); // Absolute URL
    // var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative); // Relative URL

    // Get the name of the frame in which to display the page from somewhere
    var frameName = ...

    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, frameName);
}
```